# django session serializer help choosing between pickle/json

Tags: python, django, session, pickle, serialization

I'm using django 1.6, in which the default session serializer is json. I use db as my storage engine for sessions.
I've changed this setting so now I use pickle. 
Now, after reading that: http://www.benfrederickson.com/2014/02/12/dont-pickle-your-data.html
I was surprised about the huge differences in terms of speed.
I'm aware of the security issues of pickle, but they are less concern for now, as I dont serialize data that come from users, and my website isn't that famous anyway.

I've checked my code and what I store in session are these types:
strings (ok for json)
booleans (ok for json)
datetime (not ok for json, but I could switch to string and parse it when needed)
render object(HttpRespone. not ok for json).
So as you can see I could move to json if I could just solve the last type that I store.
Basically the thing is this:
I execute an SQL query to generate some page. This page contains an iframe (google maps), which needs the same SQL output. So I don't want to perform the same SQL twice, so I just 'render' the two pages in the same view,using the same context and query output, and when I load the iframe I pull the already generated page from the session.
How can I avoid doing that? What would be a solution to generate to pages in the same view?

**EDIT**:
This is the case explained.
index.html contains an `<iframe src='/map/'>`

to generate index.html, the view is:

```
def index(request):
    output = sql_query
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'data':output})
```

Since index.html has an iframe in it, another GET request will be sent, will reach to this view:

```
def map(request):
    # Here I need the same sql output I had from the index view.
    # I don't want to perform this sql again.
    # So what I did is to create the page in index view, store it in the session,
    # and just return the page from the session. like this:
    return request.session['rendered_page_from_index_view']
```

That's why I changed to pickle serializer. Besides that I could use json. How can I avoid storing this page in the session, without doing the same sql twice?
I hope I made my point clear.

Comment: What would you store such information in the session? Django has a caching engine which pretty much can do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what the session engine is for, that is store and retrieve per-site-visitor data to overcome the stateless nature of http.

If you want to save some sql time, you want to have a look at the [cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/).

**Edit**
You should find some parameters from you request that helps you to get a unique key (maybe you can set a unique value into the session in `index` and retrieve it in `map`) and use this key to set a cache of your query set.

Pseudo-code:

```
def index(request):
    queryset = get_my_queryset()
    unique_id = get_unique_id_from_request(request)
    request.session['queryset_id'] = unique_id
    cache.set(unique_id, queryset, 30)
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'data': queryset})

def map(request):
    unique_id = request.session.get('queryset_id')
    queryset = None
    if unique_id:
        queryset = cache.get(unique_id)
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = get_my_queryset()
    return render_to_response('map.html', {'data': queryset})
```

Comment: I know what session is for.  As I've said, each user who load this page, get a page with iframe inside, both the iframe and the page needs the same sql query. the sql query is per user.  should I user cache to store rendered pages?

Comment: Then it's me who misunderstood what you are trying to achieve.If you pass your queryset from the view to the template, and inside this one your are using the query set twice, it'll be executed just once, as Django has a mechanism to cache that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

Comment: just a question. Let's say I'll use memcached as my cache engine. How does it saves the data in memory? isn't memcached use pickle as well to serialize?

Comment: Yes, it uses pickle. You can read some caveat here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets

Comment: Then what is the big difference between using memchaced, or session that uses pickle as serializer. As I see, beside the fact that the one is RAM and other is DB, no difference. But I don't understand why memcached uses pickle, and can't save objects as they are saved in python?